# Sort and Filter from an Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I have the following code:

```
var names = ["John Chuck", "Micheal Novak", "john Owen", "Rick John"];
names = _.sortBy( names, function( name ){
        return name;
     }
```

It gives me a sorted list of names. Now along with this if I want to do a filering, is it possible?

Its like, filter on 'John', so that final list has only 3 names with 'John' in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following with [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
var names = ["John Chuck", "Micheal Novak", "john Owen", "Rick John"];
names = _.sortBy( names, function( name ){
        return name;
     }).filter(n => n.toLowerCase().includes('john'));
     
console.log(names)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .includes in [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

**HTML**

```
var words = ["John Chuck", "Micheal Novak", "John Owen", "Rick John"];

const result = words.filter(word => word.includes("John"));

console.log(result); //result is: Array ["John Chuck", "John Owen", "Rick John"]
```

**Note:**
.includes is Case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

No, and in your particular case, you wouldn't give the 2nd argument, because you're sorting strings (unless you want to sort by a portion of the whole string...).

You would need to *filter*, then *sort*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Lodash.js you can also look at the _.reject function

```
names = _.reject(names, function(name) {
              return name.match(/[.]*john[.]*/i) == undefined;
        });
```

This will return only the 3 names. Have a look at - [JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gk1jfaL2/22/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple ES6 alternative (without any libs like Lodash):

```
var names = ["John Chuck", "Micheal Novak", "john Owen", "Rick John"];

var result = names.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)).filter(name => /john/gi.test(name));

console.log(result);
```